# Alternative to prepend/append_view_path in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add another directory to the paths that Rails looks in to find views, and I found a working solution in the methods ActionController::Base.prepend_view_path and ActionController::Base.append_view_path, but they are both marked as deprecated in Rails 3.  Is there an alternative that I can use?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/prepend_view_path

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/append_view_path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ActionController::Base.append/prepend_view_paths` were deprecated, as they were extracted out into the `AbstractController` module. If you call those methods from your controller, the `AbstractController` methods would be called, not the deprecated `ActionController` one.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb#L25

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is any way to make it so that I can call this once in an initializer and not have to call it every request in the ApplicationController (like with a before_filter)?

Comment: @ShyGuy Did you ever end up figuring this out? I'm having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864108/how-to-prepend-rails-view-paths-in-rails-3-2-actionviewpathset

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10865877/550712) to Kirk's question worked for me. On that question, be sure to see the updated syntax in the 4/28/2013 comment by sands.