# How can I auto-prepend a subdomain to my Rails 3 route helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a gem or plugin that allows you to add subdomains to your route helper methods based on constraints or by specifying in in the routes.rb.

It would be awesome if there was something that would do something along these lines:

```
subdomain => :admin do
  resources :posts 
end

admin_posts_url # => admin.url.com/posts
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for I think is prepend view path

```
# application_controller.rb
before_filter :subdomain_view_path

private

def subdomain_view_path
  prepend_view_path "app/views/#{request.subdomain}_subdomain" if request.subdomain.present?
end
```

you for all the details have a look at [railscasts 269](http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance?autoplay=true) (2/3 on)

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: and I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479473/alternative-to-prepend-append-view-path-in-rails-3

Comment: Cool. Will use this in the future. I was actually wondering about the url helpers.  I initially meant the path helpers. But that was stupid considering they are *path* helpers and return a path.  No need to be concerned about the subdomain with those.

Comment: My apology, the question is clear on this. also very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I manage to get my own url helper working pretty well. Basically, I have something like this :

```
def base_url
     "http://" + @actual_subdomain + "/"
end
```

And every others helper taht I wrote map to this one. Like ;

```
def category_url category
    base_url + category.slug
end
```