# How to prepend rails view paths in rails 3.2 (ActionView::PathSet)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to prepend views to the rails view array e.g.

prepend_view_path("#{Rails.root}/app/views/custom/blah")

This works fine, however in my test suite I keep seeing

**DEPRECATION WARNING: process_view_paths is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 3.2.**

After a bit of research I see mention of ActionView::PathSet, but cannot find any help searching google or in the Rails API documentation. I need to know how to use this new way of prepending paths in rails 3.2

I would really like to get rid of this warning. Any thoughts?

Comment: Rails 3.2.12 - I didn't get any notice about deprecation, neither in app log nor in rspec output

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If it is dynamic (set on a per-request basis):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_view_path

  def set_view_path
    prepend_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views/custom/blah"
  end  
end
```

I think it went to `AbstractController::ViewPaths`, but still available from controller - should be without deprecation.

If you prepend static fixed path:

```
# config/application.rb    
config.paths.app.views.unshift("#{Rails.root}/app/views/custom/blah")
```

Comment: assuming by runtime you mean on a per request basis from controller instance

Comment: Yea I mean, I have no idea what the template path could be at "compile time". It needs to be dynamic and I currently do it in the controller

Comment: I'll checkout ryans video you posted

Comment: Note, that config.paths.app... syntax is deprecated as of Rails 3.1.  I believe it should be `config.paths['app/views'].unshift...`